# How to set date to anything but the future?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program where the user has to enter a date. My questions are:

1. How can I set the date to today and the past but NOT the future?
2. How can I set the date to non-US format, i.e. dd/mm/yyyy, so the compiler reads the middle value as month?

This is what my code looks like:

```
 static DateTime date;
```

and a method like this...

```
public static void EnterDates()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
        date = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        centers[k].dates[i] = date;
        Console.WriteLine("Day " + centers[k].dates[i]);
        Console.Write("Number of movie screenings: ");
        movieScreen = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        centers[k].movieScreen[i] = movieScreen;
        Console.Write("Total number of customers: ");
        customers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        centers[k].customers[i] = customers;
        centers[k].revenue[i] = movieScreen * customers * (centers[k].Price * 1.13);
        centers[k].totalRevenue += centers[k].revenue[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I set the date to today and the past but NOT the future?

Based on what you currently have, you can add a validation after the user enters the `date` and compare it to `DateTime.Now`

```
if(date < DateTime.Now)
   //valid
else
   //invalid
```

> How can I set the date to non-US format, i.e. dd/mm/yyyy, so the
>   compiler reads the middle value as month?

You could use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
date = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```